# iOS Retina display with SDL2

Tags: ios, sdl-2, retina

I am using SDL2, and have now a little problem with it on iOS with iPhone 5S.
When I create a window, SDL will creates a window with 320x568 pixel resolution. If I use the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HDPI` flag by creating window, I can draw each pixels of the display (640x1136), but if I get the screen size with the `SDL_GetWindowSize` function I get the 320x568 px resolution back.

I tried to get the available display modes, but a display mode with 640x1136 px I have  not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you see on `SDL_GetWindowSize` method description this gives you the window size, but if you use `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HDPI` this may differ from real size.

> The window size in screen coordinates may differ from the size in pixels, if the window was created with SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI on a platform with high-dpi support (e.g. iOS or OS X).

To get the real window size in pixels you can either use `SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize()` or `SDL_GetRendererOutputSize()`.